# Ubbi Dubbi how to add ub before each vowel?

Tags: c#, string

```
Console.Write("Enter word: ");
string word = Console.ReadLine();
var loc = word.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' });

string word1 = loc >= 0 ? word.Insert(loc, "ub") : word;
Console.WriteLine(word1);
```

I get `hubello` but I want `hubellubo` instead.

Comment: You call word.insert only once. You will need to call it once per vowel. Try using a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're only doing a single modification to your string - whichever vowel you detect first. `IndexOfAny` returns only the first match found.

Instead, you'll need to find *all* the vowels in your input string. You can do this with a loop, but it might be easier to do this with Regex replacments.

```
var input = "hello";
var pattern = "([aeiou])";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "ub$1");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

The capture group is needed to re-replace the found vowel back in the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

*Linq* solution:

```
 var input = "hello";

 string replaced = string.Concat(input
   .Select(c => "aeiou".Contains(c) ? $"ub{c}" : $"{c}")); 

 Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

Here we scan each character `c` within `input` and either add `"ub"` prefix or keep character as it was.

Comment: imo best approach here

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to iterate each finding

```
string word = "hello";
char[] loc = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
int minIndex = word.IndexOfAny(loc);
while (minIndex != -1)
{
    string insert = "ub";
    word = word.Insert(minIndex, insert);
    minIndex = word.IndexOfAny(loc, minIndex + insert.Length + 1);
}
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kBPIrF